# What could cause a space between flex container rows?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

What could cause a space between flex container rows?

I have removed the link to dev project, because the answer is self-explanatory, one of items on the first row had set very high height.

There is a large gap between

*) the upper row containing `div.hlang`, `div.headerstamp.stampcont`, `div.pckHeader`,  `svg#coatArmCyprus`

*) and the lower row, containing three `div.pck` (long columns) with different contents.

What could cause the gap? Because i align all these items in `body.cont`, which is flex container with `flex-direction: row`; `justify-content: flex-start`; `align-content: flex-start`; `align-items: flex-start`;

All these items are wrapped in body.cont

```
   body.cont {
        box-sizing: border-box; 
        width: 100%; 
        position : relative; //normally nody is static
        display: flex; /* container */
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap; /* nowrap | wrap | wrap-reverse; */
        justify-content: flex-start; /* main axia : flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around | space-evenly; */
        align-items: flex-start; /* cross axis: flex-start | flex-end | center | baseline | stretch; */
        align-content: flex-start; /* all c
                                   ontainer lines : flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around | stretch; */
        margin:0; border:0; padding: 0 $bodyPadR 0 $bodyPadL; 
    }



.pck {
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    display: flex; /* container */
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* nowrap | wrap | wrap-reverse; */
    justify-content: space-around; /* flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around | space-evenly; */
    align-items: flex-start; /* cross axis: flex-start | flex-end | center | baseline | stretch; */
    align-content: flex-start; /* all container lines : flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around | stretch; */
    border:0; margin:0; padding:0;
    width:$colw; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `height: 30vw;` from the `div.hlang` rule

---

As a tip, if you right click on your page and then choose "Inspect", you can then hover the html and see how each item renders in the page.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, sems i was too tired

Comment: @olga You're welcome. Also, when an answer solves a question you are suppose to accept it, so it would be great if you do that as well.

Comment: How do you draw on the website? What tool are you using?

Comment: @olga You can use Windows Ink / Screen sketch, though in the above case I made a screen dump and then used Paint.NET to do the actual drawing